# Python -- Inserting Record from For Loop using MySQLDB

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have done the tutorials but I am far from an accomplished python hacker.

I am trying to do the following using MySQLdb:

1. loop through a list of files from a directory
2. generate a new file name for these files based on function parameters
3. insert a database record with the new filename
4. move the file to the new directory using the new filename.

I have items 1,2 and 4 working but can't get the database insert working correctly.  There is not an error but nothing is inserted into the table.  I can login and access the database through a command prompt, and I can insert a record into the table directly.

I am using python 2.75, mySQL 5.6.13, windows 7 64bit, and  MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32 installed using easy_install.

```
def moveFile(rPath, dPath, dbID):
import fnmatch
import os
import MySQLdb as mysql
import sys
conn = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='*******', passwd='*******', db='*******')
pattern = '*.pdf'
inc = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        dire = root.find(rootPath) + len(rootPath)
        dest = destPath + root[dire:]
        fname = dbID + "_" + str(inc) + ".pdf"
        # print fname
        # print os.path.join(root, filename),  os.path.join(dest, fname)
        # os.renames(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(dest, fname))
        x = conn.cursor()
        x.execute("INSERT INTO documents(documentname) VALUES (fname)")
        inc += 1

return 'Files Count: ', inc
```

I am sure I need to commit somewhere in the code but my attempts have produced no error but also no results.

Thanks for reading my question land I will try all suggestions promptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `x.execute(...)` line as follow:

```
    x.execute("INSERT INTO documents(documentname) VALUES (%s)", (fname,))
```

And commit at the end.

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Okay, I replaced the execute statement but I am not entirely sure where the commit statement should go.  I placed it at the end of the for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): loop but no records were inserted into the database.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: Well, I am an idiot.  I forgot to put the parens at the end of the commit statement.  I added those and the inserts worked.  Thanks for all your help again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely unless you commit the transaction you won't see any results in the DB. Do this after you've executed all the inserts.